# How can I personalize the header of yii\grid\checkboxColumn in GridView of Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have this code, but it only show me the label, without the checkbox, but I need both.

```
GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn'
     .....],
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
        'header' => 'Check All',
    ]
]])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand how the `CheckboxColumn` header cell is rendered check the `renderHeaderCellContent()` method of `yii\grid\CheckboxColumn` class.

If you want to set the header using default implementation of `CheckboxColumn` you should do it like this:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;

[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    'header' => Html::checkBox('selection_all', false, [
        'class' => 'select-on-check-all',
        'label' => 'Check All',
    ]),
],
```

Note that you need specify name of checkbox exactly like that - `selection_all` (unless you change the [name](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-checkboxcolumn.html#$name-detail) property).

This name is calculated dynamically (`name` concatenated with `_all` string) and then used in registered javascript. If you set it wrong, the massive selection won't be working.

Comment: hello. I need hep. I followed everything above, but when I check the header check box, it doesn't select the rest (all) of the check boxes below. why is this?